# Why does IE repeat a request with different user agent string, but without session cookie?

Tags: http, internet-explorer-11, user-agent

I have a strange behavior with a web application that produces an Excel file for download via an http get request with some parameters: If the user selects the download, according to the server log, the file is produced and sent with an http status of 200. Somehow the browser seems not to accept the file, and sends the same request about half to one second later, but *without* the session cookie and *with another user agent string*. As the second request arrives at the server without the session cookie, this causes an error, which is the only thing the user sees.

For another user, everything works without problems.

What could cause this strange behavior?

The user agent for the first request is

```
Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+Win64;+x64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko
```

(IE11 on Windows 7 64 bit). This request is sent including session cookie and referrer.

The user agent for the second request is

```
Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko
```

(IE 11 on 64bit in 32 bit emulation). This appears in the server log without referrer, and according to the error, seems to be sent without session cookie.

I could watch the user doing this this morning during a training session with our application, he did not manually click the download button in two different browsers. Furthermore, one of the parameters is the current time in milliseconds, and that matches between both requests in several cases, hence is must really be the same browser running the same request twice.

Comment: I recently noticed the same behavior... I am using the UA string to help validate sessions. Sadly I have no answer for you, I just wish to bring more attention to this issue ...